# R - mutate condition in huge data.frame

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, dplyr

So I have very large dataset (`>1000 obs. of >15000 variables`) and I wan't to replace all values `>1` with `1` and leave the rest unchanged.

Example data:

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = -1:-10, c = letters[1:10])

    a   b c
1   1  -1 a
2   2  -2 b
3   3  -3 c
4   4  -4 d
5   5  -5 e
6   6  -6 f
7   7  -7 g
8   8  -8 h
9   9  -9 i
10 10 -10 j
```

This is my `dplyr`approach:

```
data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, 
                                   funs(
                                     case_when(
                                       . >= 1 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.double(.))
                                     )
                                   )
```

This takes ages on the original data. Any idea how to speed this up? `data.table`?

Comment: Can you check with this if it improves the performance ? `data[data > 1] <- 1`

Comment: dont use case_when, in case when you only have one case.

Comment: You're right! This is just an example. Other `case_when`s will be added.

Answer (score 1):

This solution with `data.table` seems to work, to be fair it gives a `warning()`:

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
num_cols <- colnames(data)[map_lgl(data, is.numeric)] # select only the numerics 

data[, (num_cols):= lapply(.SD, function(x) {
                                    x[x>1] = 1
                                    x}),
     .SDcols=num_cols
     ]
data
# a aa   b c
# 1: 1  1  -1 a
# 2: 1  1  -2 b
# 3: 1  1  -3 c
# 4: 1  1  -4 d
# 5: 1  1  -5 e
# 6: 1  1  -6 f
# 7: 1  1  -7 g
# 8: 1  1  -8 h
# 9: 1  1  -9 i
# 10: 1  1 -10 j
```

> Warning message: In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`((num_cols),
>   lapply(.SD, function(x) { :   Supplied 2 columns to be assigned a list
>   (length 3) of values (1 unused)

Data used:

```
data <- data.table(a = 1:10, aa = 1:10, b = -1:-10, c = letters[1:10])
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr = data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, 
                              funs(
                                case_when(
                                  . >= 1 ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ as.double(.))
                              )
  ),
  datatable = data[, (num_cols):= lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    x[x>1] = 1
    x})
    ],
  times = 100
)

# Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# dplyr 1465.088 1644.7690 2012.3148 1775.4730 1989.1065 19992.621   100
# datatable  372.282  399.0235  480.9405  440.0375  547.3055   831.398   100
```

Update Ronak Shah solution is faster to be fair:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr = data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, 
                              funs(
                                case_when(
                                  . >= 1 ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ as.double(.))
                              )
  ),
  datatable = data[, (num_cols):= lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    x[x>1] = 1
    x})
    ],
  base = {dataframe <- as.data.frame(data)
          dataframe[dataframe > 1] <- 1},
  times = 100
)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
# dplyr 1782.384 1902.1210 2549.3977 1995.116 2099.9800 55628.570   100
# datatable  394.817  422.7605  466.5329  441.690  512.9020   628.282   100
# base  118.987  135.5120  160.1595  154.291  176.2255   300.469   100
```

Comment: Great approach! I think the warning comes from the one non-numeric variable. Warning disappears when this variables is excluded.

Comment: Re the warning, you should use `.SDcols=num_cols` (see `?data.table`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
apply(data[, which(sapply(data, is.numeric))], 2, 
      function(x) {ifelse(x > 1, 1, x)})
```

It leaves out the c column but you can easily merge it afterwards.